# SQL Get count with most common part of string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

I am able to get count of column with most same values, e.g.

```
SELECT     COUNT(*) AS Count, ProjectID
FROM         Projects
GROUP BY ProjectID
ORDER BY Count DESC
```

So now I have table like this,

```
ProjectID    ProjectUrl
1            http://www.CompanyA.com/Projects/123
2            http://www.CompanyB.com/Projects/124
3            http://www.CompanyA.com/Projects/125
4            http://www.CompanyB.com/Projects/126
5            http://www.CompanyA.com/Projects/127
```

### Now Expected result without providing any parameter

```
ProjectUrl = http://www.CompanyA.com Count = 3
ProjectUrl = http://www.CompanyB.com Count = 2
```

**Edit**

Sorry I forgot to mention types of Urls I have in the table, Urls are quiet random though, but there are urls that are common. As we are creating project categories, so project category url can be,

https://spanish.CompanyAa2342.com/portal/projectA/projectTeamA/ProjectPersonA/Task/124

but for some projects there are no project team or so on, so it's bit random :?

I will need to query something more like generic.

**What Url will have in common**

http://ramdomLanguage.CompanyName.com/portal/RandomName.....

Comment: You should first tell us how you want to identify the part of the ProjectUrl you want to GROUP BY... and what types of urls you have in your table.

Comment: Uhmmm... don't know if this is possible in your case, but I suggest you create a table for root urls, and then use that to JOIN the projects table and calculate the correct counts. Knowing how messed up and specific urls can be, I don't think you can get a clean cut on this just with some SUBSTR or some SQL expression snippet.

Comment: Why in the expected result there are not `http://www.CompanyA.com/Projects` and `http://www.CompanyB.com/Projects` with the same count? Are you searching only for certain type of URL?

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
select 
    Col, 
    COUNT(Col) Cnt
from(
    select
        SUBSTRING(ProjectUrl, 0, PATINDEX('%.com/%', ProjectUrl)+4) Col
    from tbl
)x group by Col
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6c020/4)

Comment: @RagingBull Yeah sure!. :)

Comment: +1, thanks TechDo, but I had to update my question regarding types of url :(, should had done it before, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of performance when dealing with a huge dataset, but this is a solution.  I've tried to get a row for each portion of the URLs, delimited by /.  Then do a quick aggregate at the end to bring up the counts of each individual part.  Fiddle is here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/742c4/12 (I've added one row for demo's sake - thanks, TechDo.)

```
WITH cteFSPositions
AS
(
    SELECT      ProjectID,
                ProjectURL,
                1 AS CharPos,
                MAX(LEN(ProjectURL)) AS MaxLen,
                CHARINDEX('/', ProjectURL) AS FSPos
    FROM        Projects
    GROUP BY    ProjectID,
                ProjectURL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT      ProjectID,
                ProjectURL,
                CharPos + 1,
                MaxLen,
                CHARINDEX('/', ProjectURL, CharPos + 1) AS FSPos
    FROM        cteFSPositions
    WHERE       CharPos <= MaxLen
),
cteProjectURLParts
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT     ProjectID,
                        LEFT(ProjectURL, FSPos) AS ProjectURLPart,
                        FSPos
    FROM                cteFSPositions
    WHERE               FSPos > 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT              ProjectID,
                        ProjectURL,
                        LEN(ProjectURL)
    FROM                Projects
),
cteFilteredProjectURLParts
AS
(
    SELECT      ProjectID,
                ProjectURLPart
    FROM        cteProjectURLParts
    WHERE       ProjectURLPart NOT IN ('http:', 'http:/', 'http://', 'https:', 'https:/', 'https://')
)

SELECT          ProjectURLPart,
                COUNT(*) AS Instances
FROM            cteFilteredProjectURLParts
GROUP BY        ProjectURLPart
ORDER BY        Instances DESC,
                ProjectURLPart;
```

This produces (with the additional row I added in):

```
ProjectURLPart                                     Instances
http://www.CompanyA.com/                                   4
http://www.CompanyA.com/Projects/                          3
http://www.CompanyB.com/                                   2
http://www.CompanyB.com/Projects/                          2
http://www.CompanyA.com/BlahblahBlah/                      1
http://www.CompanyA.com/BlahblahBlah/More1/                1
http://www.CompanyA.com/BlahblahBlah/More1/More2           1
http://www.CompanyA.com/Projects/123                       1
http://www.CompanyA.com/Projects/125                       1
http://www.CompanyA.com/Projects/127                       1
http://www.CompanyB.com/Projects/124                       1
http://www.CompanyB.com/Projects/126                       1
```

**EDIT:** Oops, original post had code of fiddle in progress.  Have supplied the finalized code and updated fiddle link.

**EDIT 2:** Realized I was cutting off the end part of the URLS due to the way I was cutting the URLs up.  For completeness' sake, I've added them back in to the final dataset.  Updated fiddle as well.